# Protractor - Asynchronous tasks in beforeEach

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am using Protractor / Jasmine to write UI Tests.
I want a particular task to be performed in all my test cases, ie. to read a span (`id="mytxt"`). So, I would like to have this task in beforeEach. like this:

```
var mytext="";
beforeEach(function(){
    element(by.id('mytxt')).getText().then(function(txt){
        mytext = txt;
    });
});

it('should ...', function(){
    expect(mytext).toBe('xyz');
});
```

Is there a way in which the test executes only after the async task in beforeEach completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `done` callback like this:

```
var mytext="";
beforeEach(function(done){
    element(by.id('mytxt')).getText().then(function(txt){
        mytext = txt;
        done();
    });
});

it('should ...', function(){
    expect(mytext).toBe('xyz');
});
```